# Center align horizontal <ul> with left-aligned rows

Tags: html, css

I am able to center horizontal list with `text-align:center`, but I wonder how can I keep it centered inside container, but has rows aligned left.

My container has percent width, so I need it working when resizing window and blocks are reordering

---

Please check the sample image below to understand my problem:
[image: Centered list]

**UPDATE:**

[Please find JsFiddle as per request](http://jsfiddle.net/au2Y5/)

I need to center my `<ul>` inside `div.container`

Comment: Seeing your code would be helpful.

Comment: could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yeah good idea, but I only will able to do it later

Comment: if count of li is fix can use the li:nt-child(7){ margin : (any)px } if NOT can't fix in css or html you need js

Comment: @masoudsoroush No, li count is always different (it is dynamic image collection actually), and when you change screen width, li should 'float' to another row

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
ul {
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ3Ap/4/):

You already know to center the `<ul>` with `margin: auto;`
The key is to adjust the `<li>` within it.

You can do that by using `float: left;`
Alternatively: you can set `display: inline-block;`
Both have a similar effect, but aren't identical. Play w/it.

By providing margins & percentage widths, you can play w/size and separation of the elements.

Since these are all block-level elements, they'll stack up & wrap automatically.
By floating or changing display of the `<li>` you keep them left-aligned within their parent element (the `<ul>`).

Also, by using separate CSS classes instead of targeting the `<li>` element directly, you leave things flexible in case you want to have a right-aligned list, or some other options later.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need my <li> to be fixed size, so when you make you screen smaller, they should reorder but not become smaller

Comment: Then used a fixed size for the width instead of a percentage.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your boxes within another `div`.

You can then center that div with `display: block; margin: 0 auto;`, while keeping the boxes left-aligned.

Comment: This adds unnecessary, non-semantic markup & doesn't quite answer the question. Centering wasn't the issue but rather how to left-align them in the first place. The ul and li are already block-level elements and can have margins & floats applied directly.

Comment: @mc01 Actually, the question clearly says "keep it centered inside container, but has rows aligned left" meaning keep the block of boxes centered, but aligned to the left.  However, I did miss the part that it is a list.

Comment: I meant that OP stated they'd already figured out how to center the overall list. Left-aligning the list items seemed to be the problem.

Comment: @mc01 I under stood it that he could do one or the other, but not both.  My bad.